# Custom authentication check for delayed web gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-authorization

currently I am using the gem `delayed-web` in my project. I have multiple user roles, and I don't wanna the users whose roles are sales can access to the page delayed web background interface. I already have a method to check for the authentication in my application controller. However, I don't know how to make it work in the route files. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**Updated**: I am not using Devise gem. I roll my own authentication.

**application_controller.rb**:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :authenticate
  before_action :check_pricer_role, except: [:export_for_customer]
  helper_method :check_pricer_role
 def check_pricer_role
    unless current_user && (current_user.pricer? || current_user.admin?)
      redirect_to errors_not_found_path
    end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # How to apply the defined authentication here?
  mount Delayed::Web::Engine, at: '/jobs'
end
```

Comment: Are you using `Devise` gem or any other?

Comment: @AlexKojin Thank you, but I don't use Devise gem in my project.

Comment: How to you authenticate users? By session? It's important to know details

Comment: I authenticate by their roles. I think it is already mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've solved the problem. It turns out that I can find the current user based on his authentication token which is saved inside of the Request object(again, I don't use any gems for authentication, I roll my own one, but I don't think that is the problem here anyway).
This is the complete solution, in case somebody way run into the same difficulty:

```
    class AuthConstraint
      def matches?(request)
        current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token(request.cookie_jar['auth_token']) if request.cookie_jar['auth_token']
         current_user.present? && !current_user.sales?
      end
    end

    Rails.application.routes.draw do
        mount Delayed::Web::Engine, at: '/jobs', :constraints => AuthConstraint.new
        //Other resources ........ 
    end
```